# Should toilet be close to sewage pump?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, basement, plumbing-fixture, remodeling

I am adding a bathroom in basement which will have a sewage pump. I am finalizing the bathroom layout and the ideal setup will have the toilet 8 ft away from the sewage pump. Is there any reason of concern like clogging issue or anything else? My layout is as below[image]

My 2nd best best option is switch the layout (top/bottom) and the toilet will then be next to sewage pump but it is not ideal layout.

Is my original layout Ok or should I make sure the toilet is next to sewage pump?

Comment: What will the drain slope (or distance and drop) from the toilet to the sewage pump be?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have proper drains and a good pump/pit for the water to drain into 8' is not a problem. Check local code as some require a larger pit when located a long distance from the toilet. I think the distance for the larger pit was based on number of levels + bathrooms.